# installing opencv Anaconda2 on windows machine

Tags: python, opencv, installation, anaconda

I'm trying to install openCV in a freshly installed Anaconda2 on a 64 bit windows machine with no luck.

I downloaded 2.4.9 form the [openCV](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) website and did pretty much which http://mathalope.co.uk/2015/05/07/opencv-python-how-to-install-opencv-python-package-to-anaconda-windows/ (and many others) suggested. Briefly, copying `cv2.pyd` from the opencv's `python\2.7\x64` folder to `Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages` folder.

When I try to import it in python I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: 1% in not a valid Win32 application.
```

any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** opencv is no longer in the conda repository, but it can be installed via binstar as follows. This example also uses a [virtual environment](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment), but you can install directly into your default if you prefer.

```
conda create --name opencv_test python=2.7

conda install --name opencv_test -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
conda info --envs
conda list --name opencv_test
activate opencv_test
# Use deactive to return to the default environment.
deactivate
# Remove test environment if you no longer need it.
conda remove --name opencv_test --all
```

Comment: at first the installation looks fine. it ended with no error messages. However i don't see opencv when i do pip list , nor i can import it in python with     import cv2 command

Comment: @Geri Conda is a replacement for pip. So in this example use `conda list --name opencv_test` if you used the name `opencv_test` for your environment. To use the environment, assuming the same name, you have to activate it with `activate opencv_test`. When you do that you should see the text `[opencv_test]` in front of your prompt. So for example: `[opencv_test] C:\Users\your_name>` Assuming all has gone well to this point, `python` and then `import cv2` should work for you.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear on this. i did everything as i was suggested. In addition i tried to install this directly into my local folder by doing `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv` . In addition to this i downloaded the wheel form Chritoph Gohlke's website and did `pip install opencv_python‑2.4.12‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl` . In ALL cases the installation went thorough with no error and the package is listed. However if i try to do `import cv2` in python i'm still getting the same error. It looks like for some reason the python sees it as a 32 bit version instead of 64.

Comment: For what it's worth, things can get messy if you have multiple Python installations. I'd uninstall everything, make sure that you clean up any leftover in your system and user path, then install a single version of Python. I'd recommend the latest 64-bit Python 3 version from Anaconda for since you're already using Anaconda, and you'll eventually run into memory issues doing scientific computing with 32-bit python. And then, with a single python installation, I'd use conda's virtual environments for specific projects.

Comment: Follow-up to the above: I tested the walk-through successfully on my machine, so there isn't a problem with the binary from binstar for example. So I suspect that a cleanup on your side may resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it's solved. It was indeed an installation issue.